# Here.com (Nokia maps) maps styling and color change

Tags: javascript, web, here-api

I am discovering usage of web maps by here.com (Navteq, Nokia) and wondering is there any option to perform color styling of the map (just like Google allows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `baseMapType`  to use any custom `ImgTileProvider` by updating the property as shown:

```
 map.set('baseMapType', baseMapProvider);
```

The Maps API for JavaScript already provides standard providers for Street Maps  (`Display.NORMAL`), Satellite Imagery (`Display.SATELLITE`) and terrain maps (`Display.TERRAIN`). If you want to extend this further, you'll need to look at the [Map Tile API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile) which offers a wider range of colors and options (and explains how to create the appropriate URLs)

[image]

Normal Street Map

[image]

Fleet Map  (add `style=fleet` to the URLs)

[image]

Night mode gray

[image]

Day mode grey

The following [map tile example](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/examples.html#map-tiles__base-map-styles-and-modes) on the HERE Maps Github Pages showcases a wide range of available tile provider options.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I'd rather create my own color theme, instead of using the prebuild ones. Is it possible. Just as i say, change only color of main roads of level 5 and up or something line that.

Comment: Not with the 2.5.3 version of the API - that level of flexibility is not available - you can only pick from the pre-defined map tile schemas. It is actually quite difficult to come up with a consistent schema which is aesthetically pleasing.